# How can I replace  " , " to " . " in  decimal or float value?

Tags: c#, sql, globalization

I have got a problem with types conversion in C# (VS2010).

I need to insert some rows in my database, but decimal number type in C#  look like this: `1,34.`

In sql string it looks : "--------`1,34`--------- ", but I need that this string looks like: "--------`1.34`-------".

How can I replace `" , "`  to `" . ".`
Thanks.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

If you want to just insert data to database put string with "." (Replace(',','.'))

Comment: interesting, what about if there is a literal string to insert containing ',' in it ?

Comment: what if the number is '123,456,789.00'

Comment: Don't understand why OP marked that answer as a solution, as it has nothing common with `globalization` tag.

Comment: It is answer because it help me. Your answers is very useful, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is NOT the correct answer and will cause trouble for you in the future, use Felice's answer.

Answer (score 18):

Use **Commands** with **parameters** to generate the db command and you will not have such problems at all, and it is the **recommended way**. See [this to have an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx). You should almost never format the sql string yourself because you always will face problems, what if you move your sw in another db culture? What about potential query injections, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Just specify an alternate culture when formatting the number to a string.

```
double value = 3.14D;

string formatted = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:F2}", value);
```

Comment: in order to me is not correct to suggest using stringformat to create sql commands.

Comment: @FelicePollano - I agree, I was simply answering his specific query.

Answer (score 2):

If you have decimal in your database, and you have decimal in your code you do not need any conversion, you are ready to go.

However I am afraid you think this is a decimal

> "3.14"

It is not. It is a string which holds decimal representation, IOW it is visualization of the number for mortal beings.

If you need a conversion it is a sign either you push strings to numbers, or numbers to strings. The second means you have a broken design, the first you a parsing some messy input from external source -- in such case my preference is to create a Culture object and then set its features according to the messy source, for example:

```
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

Then use this object while converting data.

Answer (score 0):

This does not depend on C# but on the default culture you are using. 
You need to format your decimals using a culture of your choice, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk.aspx) for help

Answer (score 0):

You can set `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` for any CultureInfo you use:

```
  // Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
  NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

  // Displays a value with the default separator (".").
  Int64 myInt = 123456789;
  Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

  // Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
  nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = " ";
  Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
```

This is an example from msdn

Answer (score 0):

See this previous answer.

[Stack Overflow Globalised Number Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902450/globalized-custom-number-formatting-variable-decimal-points)

However you should not have to do this simply to get a number in your database.
if you use a parameterised query

In the database the number is just a decimal. If I write an application here in the UK, when it's converted to a string for display I see 9,999.999 You write one you see 9.999,999.

Im using a UK culture, you'd be using yours
So look at why you need to mix cultures, see if you can remove the need, very rare you actually need this sort of thing, even less so in .Net as it was engineered to get rid of all the problems previous incarnations of windows had caused.